# What is a way I can copy over only cells that respond to a certain criteria (a string on both sides) to a different sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, range, formula, criteria

I have a list of trades. They have their own info, etc. I want each trade to show up in its own sheet for data purposes with some kind of formula. Say I have 12 products, my entire list of trades follows the same logic, for example all trades begin with either PH- or QH-, and end with -01 to -96. I want a row to appear in a certain sheet if the criteria is met - for example, I want to move all trades that pertain to PH-01, which shows up as, for example, PH-2024-0331-01 FROM the main trades list to a sheet called PH1. Every cell from the row of that trade needs to be moved, but it's all dependent on which product this trade is for. So if I have a list of trades with several different columns, moving one of the rows to, say, sheet PH2 is only dependent on whether the trade pertains to PH2.
The trade itself has several properties:
ID   / type   / portfolio   / who / etc. as you can see in the photo. [Here is how the trade list looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCP0n.png)
Once again, I want to move a trade that begins with PH- and ends with -01 to sheet PH1. Moving the other columns is dependent on whether the trade pertains to that sheet. Every column in the receiving sheet would be a formula, which I will tweak or drag. What is a way that I can do this, so I can sort the trades easier?
If this is not possible the way I am explaining, please let me know.

I tried LEFT() and MID(), I tried variations of IF, but I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support FILTER?

Comment: I am stupid, FILTER under Data, yes, both Offices I use support it. I can filter the data that way, but I still have to manually paste it into anywhere from 24-120 separate sheets because I need the data to be separate for each product, since one product can have tens or even hundreds of trades.

Comment: I actually meant the FILTER formula originally but now think VBA might be a good solution here.